# How to change phone number format using Inputmask?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an input field for a phone number , need make fixed first 3 number (user can not delete it , )

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#phone-1").inputmask("+996 111 222222",{ "clearIncomplete": true });
});
```

How would you go about this problem?

Work Phone is an example of the default functionality of the [Mask input plugin.](https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask)

Comment: You can keep 3 Digit outside input.

Comment: I want it was in input, when user send phone number

Comment: If 3-numbers are fix, you can concat prefix at the time of form submission. Its just a workaround. For more you have to read library if it supports such functionality.

Answer (score 1):

```js
   
 
$(document).ready(function() {
   $.mask.definitions['#'] = $.mask.definitions['9'];  //Set # to do what 9 does
   $.mask.definitions['9'] = null;                     //Remove 9 as a masking character
   $("input").mask("(099) ###-###-###");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
 
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.maskedinput/1.4.1/jquery.maskedinput.min.js"></script> 
<div>
   <input type="text">
</div>
```

Comment: for  https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask  how can I remove 9 as a masking character ?

Comment: $.mask.definitions['9'] = null;                     //Remove 9 as a masking character

Comment: This is wrong code, not working    $.mask.definitions['9'] = null;

Comment: What's wrong in this code can you Run the code above and check?

Comment: I can not do it with https://github.com/RobinHerbots/Inputmask ??